# Chrome bug when using box-shadow and relative elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, box-shadow

So I think I found this bug in Chrome where scrollbars glitches when using box-shadow and `position: relative`. I'd like to know whether it really is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

It took me quite a few hours to figure what caused this problem. Here's a short description of what causes this bug. My html structure looks like this.

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.fixed` has a fixed position and a box-shadow. `.container` is just a container for the scrollable content. `.block`s are there to just simulate content. This structure makes the scrollbar shift to the left and up. Here's a link to the [pen](http://codepen.io/mageteus/pen/dpmGWy) where you can see the issue live. You need to have a Mac and Chrome browser. I tested it on Windows and the issue wasn't present there.

In the pen you can reproduce the issue by uncommenting the box-shadow line and fix the issue by either commenting the `position: relative` line for the `.block` or the box-shadow line.

I'm using 2015 MacBook Pro 13" (macOS Sierra) and Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit).

And here's also an image of the issue.
[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGBP7.png)